# How to show $\log \cosh(\sqrt x)$ is concave?

Tags: convex-analysis

I know the definition of convex and concave functions and the second order condition to justify convexity (concavity). But still, I do not know how to show $\log \cosh(\sqrt x)$ is concave.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A better title would be "how to show ..." rather than "why..."  The latter sounds like a philosophical question.

Comment: I believe the second derivative is $\frac1{4x}-\frac14\frac{\sinh\sqrt{x}}{x^{3/2}\cosh\sqrt{x}}-\frac14\frac{\sinh(\sqrt{x})^2}{x\cosh(\sqrt{x})^2}$

Comment: What's the domain of the function? $x>0$? Or is it all real numbers?

Comment: @GregoryGrant. I think that the second derivative is $\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{\text{sech}^2\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{x}-\frac{\tanh
   \left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{x^{3/2}}\right)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici GregoryGrant's expression is correct

Comment: @GregoryGrant changed :-) but how can you test concavity from the expression you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x>0$ the [second derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diff(diff(log(cosh(sqrt(x))),x),x);) is:
$$\frac{\text{sech}^2\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{4x}-\frac{\tanh    \left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{4x^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{4x\cosh(\sqrt{x})} \left(\frac{1}{\cosh(\sqrt{x})}-\frac{\sinh    \left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$$
Hence the second derivative is negative (and our function is concave) as soon as we show that for $t>0$,
$$f(t):=\sinh(t)\cosh(t)-t=\frac{\sinh(2t)}{2}-t>0$$
which holds because $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is strictly increasing in $[0,+\infty)$ since $f'(t)=\cosh(2t)-1>0$ for $t>0$.